# How to get Array type data in Firebase in Kotlin?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore, android-jetpack-compose

I have this type of array in firebase but how to fetch it and use in kotlin
I was able to get as String but how to get its as a `data` `class`
 Like this

```
data class Comment(
    val uid: String,
    val comment: String,
    val stamp: Timestamp
)
```

and here's the code of getting string

```
var text by remember { mutableStateOf("loading...") }
FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("MyApp")
  .document("Something").get().addOnSuccessListener {
     text = it.get("Comments").toString()
}
```

[image: Check this iage]

Comment: please share the code that you receive `String` from Firebase

Comment: I think that this article, [How to map an array of objects from Cloud Firestore to a List of objects?](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-map-an-array-of-objects-from-cloud-firestore-to-a-list-of-objects-122e579eae10) might help.

Comment: I faced the same problem. I don't know how Firebase represents this arrays...

Comment: I hope, the article above will help us, written clearly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase has a `toObject` method that can be used to turn your document into a custom object.

```
db.collection("Comments")
    .get()
    .addOnSuccessListener { documents ->
        for (document in documents) {
            val comment = document.toObject<Comment>()
        }
    }
```

The `Comment` data class should also define default values. So, it should be like...

```
data class Comment(
    val uid: String = "",
    val comment: String = "",
    @ServerTimeStamp val stamp: Date? = null
)
```

Comment: Please see my code once again :) and its has a list of comment `object`

Comment: Danartillaga your solution crashes with this error `java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not deserialize object. Class Comment does not define a no-argument constructor. If you are using ProGuard, make sure these constructors are not stripped`

Comment: It should be fixed by adding default values for the ```Comment``` class. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks Done after some Modifications

Answer (score 0):

I got ArrayLists with HashMaps represents my entities entities just using this:

```
                val cleanAnswers: List<Answer> = (document.get(FIELD_ANSWERS)
                        as ArrayList<HashMap<String, Any>>).map {
                    Answer(
                            it[FIELD_VARIANT] as String,
                            it[FIELD_IS_CORRECT] as Boolean
                        )
                }
```

My entity:

```
class Answer(val answer: String,
         val isCorrect: Boolean) : Serializable
```